# Correct path for =IMPORTXML on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

This URL: https://www.screwfix.com/p/makita-jr3050t-2-1010w-reciprocating-saw-240v/27338

Trying to use IMPORTXML on google Sheets to pull in the price (119.99 as of today)

Using the following formula:

(via Google Developer Tab, right-click Copy XPath)

> =IMPORTXML(https://www.screwfix.com/p/makita-jr3050t-2-1010w-reciprocating-saw-240v/27338, "//*[@id='product_price']/text()")

Or

> =IMPORTXML("https://www.screwfix.com/p/makita-jr3050t-2-1010w-reciprocating-saw-240v/27338","//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content")

Or

> =importxml(https://www.screwfix.com/p/makita-jr3050t-2-1010w-reciprocating-saw-240v/27338, "//div[@class='pr__price']")

Plus a few other variations - Unfortunatley, they all come out as #N/A

Can anyone help me find the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in this case, when the URL is retrieved by `IMPORTXML()`, most values are included in `head`. When I tried this URL, `body` retrieved by `IMPORTXML()` was empty. So how about this workaround?

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//head/*"),"(\d.+)INC")
```

- Please put the URL of `https://www.screwfix.com/p/makita-jr3050t-2-1010w-reciprocating-saw-240v/27338` to the cell "A1" and put the formula to other cell.
- In this workaround, the value you want is retrieved from the values retrieved from `head`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether this formula can be used for other URL. If you want to use this for other URL, please confirm the values and set the xpath and regex.
- If you use Google Apps Script, I think that the value can be retrieved from the body of URL.

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you - that looks good. It definitely gets me the price info I'm after. I don't know how I would use this to pull other elements such as the description though, so it might be limited in it's use.<br>Looking at the REGEXTRACT Code, am I right in saying it's pulling any numeric data with a decimal point? Or does it work differently than I think?<br>There is a LOT of unstructured data pulled out of the <head> section, but yes, nothing in the <body>.

Comment: @JP1977 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When I checked the data of URL, I noticed that the result retrieved using UrlFetchApp of Google Apps Script was different from the result of IMPORTXML. By this, I proposed this workaround. But I'm not sure whether this is the best way. So for example, I think that if you use UrlFetchApp, you can also retrieve the values using tags (But this is not XPath.).